# Is $f(x)=x^n\ln(x^n)$ for even $n\in\mathbb{N}$ odd or even?

Tags: calculus

Is $f(x)=x^n\ln(x^n)$ for even $n\in\mathbb{N}$  odd or even function?

Comment: What is $f(-x)$? You know that $n$ is even so what does that imply?

Comment: BUT: $f(x)=nx^n\ln(x)$

Comment: No $\ln(x^n)=n\ln(x)$ is only valid when $x>0$. You cannot bring the exponent down in this case.

Comment: For $n$ even, it would be $f(x) = n x^n \ln(|x|)$. But yes, EdoCvardo is right: the function is even.

Answer (score 1):

An even function must satisfy: $$f(x)=f(-x).$$
Let's check whether $x^n\ln(x^n)$ for even integers $n$ satisfies this property: $$f(x)=x^n\ln(x^n)=(-x)^n\ln((-x)^n)=f(-x)$$ since $x^n=(-x)^n\,\color{grey}\forall x\in\Bbb R$ given $n$ is even. Now conclude.